# Load html page as content of tab in Angular typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to add a html page as content of a tab in Angular. I've tried to do this with the mat-tab-nav-bar and a mat-tab-link, but it sends me to a new page instead of showing the contents as body of the current tab.

current code:

```
<p>This is a page to test your Java skills</p>
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar backgroundColor="primary" color="primary">
  <a mat-tab-link
     routerLinkActive="active"
     [routerLink]="['/questions']"> Questions
  </a>
</nav>

<div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
```

What should I do to show the html page as content of the current tab?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want the `javascript` tag here, not `java`.

Comment: you probably want to remove `/` from your route, since this is an absolute route and not targeting child routes. Can you provide your route config?

Comment: it works with or without the /,
I've posted my routing config below. The links do work when I click them, they only open in a new page, instead of below my current tab.
I want the link to show the html page below my current tab, in its body.

Answer (score 0):

this is the routing config

````
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {QuestionlistComponent} from "./questions/question-overview/questionlist.component";
import {QuestionDetailComponent} from "./questions/question-detail/question-detail.component";
import {NewQuestionFormComponent} from "./questions/new-question-form/new-question-form.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'questions', component: QuestionlistComponent},
  {path: 'questions/:id', component: QuestionDetailComponent},
  {path: 'post-question', component: NewQuestionFormComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }```
````

Answer (score 0):

If the component that has the mat-tab is the Home.component you should to have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent,children:[
     {path: 'questions', component: QuestionlistComponent},
     {path: 'questions/:id', component: QuestionDetailComponent},
     {path: 'post-question', component: NewQuestionFormComponent}
  ]}
]
```

NOTE: You can put the mat-tab in the main-component and use your routes